# Accessing arguments of console.log.bind()

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to implement a log service that adds a prefix to a log message, keeps the original line number and does some additional stuff with the message. I am returning `console.error.bind` to keep the original line number.

```
get error() {
    // additional stuff
    return console.error.bind(console, "[ERROR]");
}
```

To log something:

```
logService.error("message");
```

Is there a way to access the error message in the getter function? arguments.length is always 0.

Comment: Nope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would be a starting point?

```js
let err = console.error
console.error = function(s){err("prefixed " + s)}

console.error("Error Message")
```

Comment: This results to `prefixed Error Message (line 2)`. It does not keep the original line number 4 where the error was actually thrown.

Comment: can you provide an example that I could test?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function logService(){
   this.error = function(message) {
       throw new Error(message);
   }

}

let test = new logService()
test.error('to your computer');
```

create a wrapper around like this

Comment: A wrapper like this does not keep the original line number. Your example results to `something happenedto your computer (line 3)` but I would like to see the line number of where the error was thrown (line 9).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to access the error message in the getter function?

No. The getter runs when the property is accessed, before the method (the function returned by the getter) is called with the error message as its argument.